# Sublist extraction in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a piece of code to solve the following assignment. I have a two-column dataset with the following structure: a "country" column, which contains names of countries that repeat many times (e.g. "USA", "China","Italy", "USA",...), and a "date" column, that assign to each country a specific calendar date.

Other than this dataset, I also have a list of integers (e.g. 3,5,3,2...), the sum of which is equal to the number of appearances, in the first dataset, of the country "USA".

My goal is to use the list of integers to extract from the dataset only the first row containing "USA" for every interval in the list: it will be much clearer with an example: since the first integer in the list is 3, I would like the code to extract the first "USA" row it finds, starting from the top, and discard the following two; the second integer is 5, so that means that the next "USA" row found should be kept and the following four discarded. And so on.

I have tried many different pieces of code, but none of them worked. If you have any advice it would be great!

Comment: add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can do that basically with `cumsum` to get the position in the list.
It works like this:

```
# define your list of groups
# as stated in your post from each group take
# the firstoccurance (so in this case
# the 1st, the 4th, the 9th and the 12th)
selection= [3, 5, 3, 2]

# calculate the actual positions
# and store them in list take
# in the example it will contain
# 1, 4, 9, 12
pos=1
take= list()
for i in selection:
    take.append(pos)
    pos+= i

# create an indexer that "marks" the
# rows with the country in question
country_indexer= df['country']=='USA'
# number each occurance starting from 1
# for the first match
# so we get a position as we need it
# to match it with the take list
pos_in_country= country_indexer.cumsum()

# now filter it
df[country_indexer & pos_in_country.isin(take)]
```

The result is:

```
Out[20]: 
   country        date
0      USA  2019-08-22
4      USA  2019-08-26
14     USA  2019-09-05
18     USA  2019-09-09
```

For the following test data the numbers in brackets are actually not part of the test data, they are just to show the position:

```
Out[145]: 
   country       date   
0      USA 2019-08-22   (1)
1      USA 2019-08-23   (2)
2       MX 2019-08-24   
3      USA 2019-08-25   (3)
4      USA 2019-08-26   (4)
5       MX 2019-08-27   
6      USA 2019-08-28   (5)
7      USA 2019-08-29   (6)
8       MX 2019-08-30   
9       MX 2019-08-31   
10      MX 2019-09-01   
11      MX 2019-09-02   
12     USA 2019-09-03   (7)
13     USA 2019-09-04   (8)
14     USA 2019-09-05   (9)
15      MX 2019-09-06   
16     USA 2019-09-07  (10)
17     USA 2019-09-08  (11)
18     USA 2019-09-09  (12)
19      MX 2019-09-10  
20     USA 2019-09-11  (13)
21     USA 2019-09-12  (14)
22      MX 2019-09-13  
23      MX 2019-09-14
```

To generate the test dataframe, you can use:

```
from numpy import datetime64
data= {'country': ['USA', 'USA', 'MX', 'USA', 'USA', 'MX', 'USA', 'USA', 'MX', 'MX', 'MX', 'MX', 
                   'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'MX', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'MX', 'USA', 'USA', 'MX', 'MX'],
 'date': [datetime64('2019-08-22'), datetime64('2019-08-23'),
  datetime64('2019-08-24'), datetime64('2019-08-25'), datetime64('2019-08-26'), datetime64('2019-08-27'),
  datetime64('2019-08-28'), datetime64('2019-08-29'), datetime64('2019-08-30'), datetime64('2019-08-31'),
  datetime64('2019-09-01'), datetime64('2019-09-02'), datetime64('2019-09-03'), datetime64('2019-09-04'),
  datetime64('2019-09-05'), datetime64('2019-09-06'), datetime64('2019-09-07'), datetime64('2019-09-08'),
  datetime64('2019-09-09'), datetime64('2019-09-10'), datetime64('2019-09-11'), datetime64('2019-09-12'),
  datetime64('2019-09-13'), datetime64('2019-09-14')]}

df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```